# XAML invoke command for middle mouse click (System.Windows.Interactivity)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`System.Windows.Interactivity` allows commands to be invoked when a specific event is triggered, without having to write code behind. However, I couldn't find out how to invoke a command when the middle mouse button (scroll wheel) is clicked on an element.

```
<StackPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="...">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Most mouse wheels cannot be clicked. So this isn't an event even recognised as a different event by generic mouse drivers.

Comment: I could give you something allows you to bind mousewheel scroll - or you could probably google it.  I grabbed an implementation off the net some time back.

Comment: @Andy, middle click exists and very useful. https://lifehacker.com/the-many-things-you-can-do-with-a-middle-click-on-your-1565756062

Comment: Okaydokes. Never seen an implementation myself.

Comment: Turns out that mousebinding works with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy's answer showed, you can use mouse binding. However the `WheelClick` gesture indicates a scroll action, use `MiddleClick` instead.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
    </StackPanel.InputBindings>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Ash pointed out that clicking the wheel button was a thing, it prompted me to look into how that would work.
You can just use a mousebinding.

```
<StackPanel.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="WheelClick" Command="{Binding WheelClickCommand}" />
</StackPanel.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, the command is only invoked when the mouse wheel is scrolled instead of clicked.

Comment: Apparently, there is also a gesture `MiddleClick` which seems to do the job as well!

Comment: The code above isn't just air code - it worked when I tried it. Maybe mouse drivers or settings make a difference.

Comment: You can find the different MouseActions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouseaction?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: Or maybe I was rotating a bit as I clicked. Shrug.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `EventTrigger` that handles this for you:

```
public class MouseWheelButtonEventTrigger : System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger
{
    public MouseWheelButtonEventTrigger()
    {
        EventName = "MouseDown";
    }

    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        MouseButtonEventArgs mbea = eventArgs as MouseButtonEventArgs;
        if (mbea != null && mbea.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Middle)
            base.OnEvent(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
<StackPanel Background="Yellow" Width="100" Height="100">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <local:MouseWheelButtonEventTrigger>
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
        </local:MouseWheelButtonEventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</StackPanel>
```

The built in one doesn't as there is no specific event raised for the mouse wheel button.

Comment: Thank you, this is an elegant solution!